# ICloud multiple user (different iCloud accounts) via public database?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, icloud, cloudkit

It occurs to me that to provide multi user support for an app using iCloud, a public access container could be used. From a security point of view, only my app has access to the container anyway.

I'm just wondering if this is a viable idea? Or are there implications I haven't considered / mentioned?

I was thinking I could cover the cost via a subscription. I guess I could also monitor usage and have heavy / light user subscription tiers.

Comment: Jules I don't really understand the question. Multiuser support in what context? Your question is a little too vague?

Comment: Sharing iCloud data on different devices / different Apple IDs. But still limiting the users to say a family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid strategy. I've implemented something like this in an app by allowing the user to log in to "nearby classrooms" (accounts) that were guarded by a passcode. This requires your app client being the authority on whether or not the user can see a piece of data, though, where this is normally handled by the server.